# Storing error message in string after error has occured java?

Tags: java, string, error-handling, printstream

I need to store an error message in a string after the error has occurred. I am unable to use the try and catch blocks as the error will appear after the initial code is run.

Before I was using the code below to store the error message in a file when it appeared:

```
PrintStream printS = new PrintStream("file.txt");  
System.setErr(pst);
```

However I want to store it and a string and send this string else where after the error occured. I have tried already using a byte array output stream:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream printS = new PrintStream(byteArray);  
System.setErr(pst);
String tester = byteArray.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

But when I try to print the string it is empty and does not contain the error. Does anyone know how I can run code after a error has occurred, so I can send this error message elsewhere?

Comment: You are creating byteArray, and the trying the byteArray.toString. You are no using it.

Answer (score 0):

Java just runs code on the spot, you're not defining triggers for the future. You are creating a new empty byte array output stream, setting it up as 'target' for any `System.err` calls later, and then **immediately** turning it into a string. It's still blank at this point, of course.

What you want is quite complicated - you'd have to write a custom PrintStream that saves anything sent to it, until it 'sees' a newline and then acts. Something like:

```java
OutputStream myCustomReportingStream = new OutputStream() {
  ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  @Override public void write(int b) {
    if (b == '\r') continue;
    if (b == '\n') {
      process(new String(buffer.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      buffer.reset();
    } else {
      buffer.write(b);
    }
  }

  private void process(String message) {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
  }
};
System.setErr(new PrintStream(myCustomreportingStream, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

A bunch of things are happening here:

- We're defining a custom OutputStream which buffers everything sent to it, until it sees `\n` (which is "newline" in ASCII, UTF-8, and many other encodings), at which point it turns the buffer into a string, sends that string to the `process` method, and clears out the buffer. It also ignores `\r` to deal with `\r\n` which is windows-style newlines.
- We then use that OutputStream as basis for a new PrintStream, and then set up syserr to use this printstream.
- This code does not deal with anything that sends data to System.err but doesn't send a newline symbol.
- Anytime anybody anywhere runs `System.err.println`, your `process()` method will be run.

Comment: thankyou, but the code above has one error, that is "The method getBytes() is undefined for the type ByteArrayOutputStream".

Comment: I wrote it from memory - just check the API docs. It's .toByteArray() or some such.